# He took her into dinner

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He took her into dinner.

Does the sentence above mean that he's going to buy her dinner so he took her to a restaurant to have dinner together? Or he guided/escorted her to a restaurant?

Comment: It makes sense if they were at a house with a dining room and he took her (escorted her) into that room at dinner time.

Comment: What if they are in a city and just on the road? Then, does the sentence mean he takes her to a restaurant to have dinner together?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: Please do not post random sentences without saying where you saw it. One can make  up stuff about just anything, in terms of answering. They were at the golf club and he took her into dinner [in the dining room].

Comment: In a dictionary as an example sentence. Dinner is a meal people eat in the evening. Why did you say 'Likewise breakfast or tea'?

Comment: We eat dinner in the middle of the day in our house, and tea in the evening.

Comment: At formal dinners in the past, it was the custom for each gentleman to escort a lady guest (not his wife) into the dining room, sit next to her and make polite conversation.

Comment: In a dictionary as an example of what word? I am voting to close as lacking any contex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the sentence should properly be:

> (1) He took her in to dinner.

The difference may not be obvious if this is spoken aloud, rather than written.

Taking her **into** dinner would seem to imply the he somehow took her **inside** dinner, which seems to make no sense.

Sentence (1) could have several meanings. It could mean that he was her escort on a formal occasion where couples go in to dinner together. Some weddings, for example, follow this custom. So do some dinner parties.

Or it could mean that he led hr to the dining room on a less formal occasion, perhaps because she weas a guest and did not know the way.

Or it could mean that he led her into a restaurant for dinner. In this case he may have acted as host, in which case he may have paid the bill, but that is not as safe or automatic an assumption as it once might have been, nor does the sentence directly state that.

The wording of (1) would not be a likely way to express "he guided/escorted her to a restaurant".

One cannot be sure of the intended meaning without context.